# Model binding issue in Release mode

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am seeing some odd behavior with one of our WebAPI projects. One of the resources has a POST action that accepts a complex .Net object and one of the properties is an enum like so:

```
public class MyComplexClass {
  public string Prop1 { get; set; }
  public MyEnum Val { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum {
   Val1,
   Val2
}
```

When I call this endpoint from another .Net project it works just fine as long as my WebAPI project has been compiled & deployed in **Debug** mode. The moment I compile it in **Release** mode, the model binding starts behaving weird. The value of my `MyEnum` is always `Val1` even if I pass in `Val2` or 1. I just cannot seem to explain what is going on here and have run out of ideas.

**EDIT**
I have a helper that serializes objects and adds them to the body and makes the call to the WebAPI. I call it similar to something like this:

```
client.Post<MyComplexClass, bool>(new MyComplexClass() { Prop1="Hello"; Val=MyEnum.Val2});
```

I am sharing the models between the projects and I am using the same model `MyComplexClass` in this case when I serialize it and when I accept it as a parameter in my Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool UpdateUserPassword(MyComplexClass request)
{
    Log(request.Val);
}
```

The value of request.Val is different depending on if it is compiled in **Debug** or **Release** mode. For release it is always `Val1` which I am guessing is because it is getting defaulted to 0 and interpreting that as `Val1`

Comment: Odd issue, but I think we would need to have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help.

Comment: Have you attempted to trace the service to see what is actually being passed.

Comment: The caller is passing the exact same set of values in the body to the WebAPI. But the WebAPI seems to read the property that has the enum as 0 and hence sets it to Val1.

Comment: Can you provide an example that behaves this way?

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens when you call the endpoint via fiddler?

Comment: Calling with Fiddler has the same effect.

Comment: Are you using WebAPI2 ?

Comment: @su8898 No,not using WebAPI2.

Comment: I know this is an old but just in case it helps someone i was having a very similar issue. This is how i resolved it https://forums.asp.net/t/2122025.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at what actually goes out over the wire. Use browser testing tools, or fiddler.
2. To help diagnose: initialize your enum explicitly and include a default `0` value. `None=0,Val1=1,Val2=2` this will help figure out if it is the binding, serialization, or transmission layers (things inside your app, but outside your control, like asp.net or iis).

If that looks fine:

1. Compare the installed and loaded assemblies and versions, Dev to prod.
2. Compare the web.config files.
3. Compare the machine.config files
4. Verify the expected deployed assemblies are actually getting deployed.
5. Make sure prod is pointing to the deploy target

Comment: All of these except the machine.config I have compared. They are all the same. The obvious differences are the dll sizes when in Debug and Release modes. Other than that everything seems to be exactly the same.

Comment: Including what is sent over the wire? The actual value sent?

Comment: Have you copied the assemblies down from prod and disassembled them to compare those sections of code?

Comment: @Maslow OP has already stated that it's the WebAPI that is changing it's configuration not the client, so the data being sent can't be different.

Comment: @Maslow Yes I have disassembled and compared and they are still the same.

Comment: @DavidG almost by definition (excluding a scenario where dev and prod are hot swapped via cloud or something) the client is doing SOMETHING different if it goes to prod instead of dev. It may just be the url but it could be as much as different browsers, or what's sent down into the browser before the web api call is actually coming down different

Comment: @Maslow Yes, but OP isn't saying he is changing the server to prod, just that the compile mode affects the results. To me that means he is seeing the same effect on his dev environment. In other words, open the WebAPI project, run it in debug mode, test. Run it again in release config and test again with different results.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not using WebAPI2, [it's safe to assume](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx) that enum values are not parsed correctly on the WebAPI side. Why the parsing works in debug mode but not in release mode in the same machine is strange though. You can try passing the enum value as a string and then doing [Enum.Tryparse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public class MyComplexClass 
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Val { get; set; }
}
```

and in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public bool UpdateUserPassword(MyComplexClass request)
{
     MyEnum myenum = MyEnum.Val1; 
     if(Enum.Tryparse(request.Val,true, out myenum)
     {
          Log(myenum);
     }
     else
     {
          // invalid enum value POSTed
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar. I tried int and it always got a 0. Not sure if string would help but will give that a shot.